# How to manipulate view value without affecting the original variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to change the view value of the ng-model in angularjs without affecting the underlying model variable.I have defined a scope variable markPercent in the controller.

```
$scope.markPercent = 0.43;
```

And i am trying to access the same from my view using ng-model.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="markPercent">
```

This input is displaying 0.43 in the view html. And what i wanted is 43 in the view html without affecting the value of **$scope.markPercent**. Also if the user is changing the value in the input field that should modify the scope variable in the same way (Eg: if the user is inputting 65 then $scope.markPercent should be 0.65). In fact i dont want to multiply and divide it with 100 each and everytime inside a watch(That is how i do now). How does it we do in angular way ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jeffjohnson9046/9470800

Comment: A filter cannot do 2-way binding as the op wants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the case for the `ngModel.$parsers`/`ngModel.$formatters` pipelines ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)). You will need a directive that `require`s the `ngModel` and puts its own code into those two pipelines. E.g.:

```
app.directive("percent", function() {
    /** Convert a string view value to percent float from 0.0 to 1.0. */
    function parser(value) {
        // implement this
    }

    /** Convert a float from 0.0 to 1.0 to percent. */
    function formatter(value) {
        // implement this
    }

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.push(parser);
            ngModel.$formatters.push(formatter);
        }
    };
});
```

Working example with simplistic parser/formatter: http://jsfiddle.net/748j30ha/